# php session value is not working in chrome browser?

Tags: php, angularjs, web-services, google-chrome, restful-authentication

While accessing the session value of server it throws the undefined index error because of losing session value..

can any brilliant say that why it occurs?

Detail description of this question is

[php session value is not working in chrome browser but working in postman?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629921/php-session-value-is-not-working-in-chrome-browser-but-working-in-postman)

Comment: Do you mean it's giving you an error in PHP for the `$_SESSION[]` variable? Are you setting the session correctly? Can you post your code? Have you tested it with other browsers? They work? Your question isn't that clear...

Comment: @Axiom can you please go through this link , it's my previous detail post of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629921/php-session-value-is-not-working-in-chrome-browser-but-working-in-postman)

Comment: @Axiom did you clearly understand of my question ?

Comment: Where is the code where you set and retrieve $_SESSION[] value? It can't be found in your other question either.

Comment: @rehmat if you wish i can share my screen and explain the real issue here, can you help me?